# Indicate when there is something to review

Tags: feature-request, review

I find myself going to the review section quite often, but most of the time, there is nothing to review. It would be cool if there was some kind of indication that there are elements to review instead of going to the page to find out that there is nothing.

Something like bold fonts for the review link, or a number between parenthesis. Or anything else really, just an indicator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a greasemonkey script to do this (they work in Firefox and Chrome). It adds an indicator before the link list that shows the total number of review items in all queues:

[image]

[source code](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/154162), [direct install link](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/154162.user.js)

Comment: That's cool, thanks! However, Chrome blocks the auto-installation of the script, I had to install it manually through the extensions menu. But I do believe that this could be added to StackExchange by default, because I don't think that everyone know that these scripts exist.

Comment: @marco-fiset - with stuff like this the first port of call is always an add on script. If it's then deemed useful it can be implemented as part of the site.

Comment: @marco-fiset - You can install the script, you just have to drag and drop it to the opened Extensions window in Chrome. Google made it easier to protect the n00bs from getting click-jacked, which makes it harder to actually install the darn things.

Comment: Hey Michael, you should think about putting these scripts up on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com). I bet people would love this, as well as the [SO Flags script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66724/155826).

Comment: @jmort253 Yeah that's what I did, as I said in my first comment ;)